# Postgresql: How do use full text search without adding extra column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a large "users" table with a "description" field. There is already an index created as below:

```
CREATE INDEX user_fts_index ON user
    USING GIN (TO_TSVECTOR('english', description));
```

Now, can I simply use above index to speed up my searches? Any example I see, asks me to create a new "auto-generated" column which is difficult now because the table is too large.

Example of my query:

```
select distinct "public"."user"."id"
from "public"."user"
where to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'test')
```

I'm using PG 15.3.

P.S.

Result of Explain Analyse:
[image: Result of Explain Analyse]

Comment: According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-indexes.html) you are correct, there is no need to use to_tsvector function in your query. Run your query with `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see if there is room for optimization in the execution plan (add it to your question).

Comment: Your plan shows that the index is being used.  Is that not the answer to your own question?  What is left to be answered?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. The problem is, my queries take longer than expected to run. Like ~10s for a table with 60M rows. I would expect faster executions. Thought maybe this has something to do with the indexing.

Comment: You should also capture buffer usage, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Also make sure track_io_timing is turned on.  The plan you showed was 70 times faster than 10s.  It will be hard to tell what the issue is without catching it in the act of being slow.  Auto_explain (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) can be useful for that.